# {mysql} select with a cross join

Tags: mysql, select, join

im currently a little bit confused about my sql select.
i got something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

with data of:

```
INSERT INTO `a` (`id`, `ip`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 2147483647, 'foobar'),
(2, 2372224735, 'foobar2');
```

so i would like append another table to the result of

```
select * from a
```

means:

```
select * from a cross join (select * from b where ip <= a.ip order by ip desc limit 1)
```

but it isnt working, i have no idea how to fix it :/

any ideas?

Thanks advance!

Comment: What's the schema of b and what's the output you expect?

Comment: the schema of table b contains ip details, i would like to append the content to the select row of table "a"

Comment: why not simple left/right/inner join and why cross join?

Comment: why appending? You can simply get by join where ip matches in both table.

Comment: i need to limit the result (limit 1) of the where clausel, ive not founded any way to get this done

Comment: limit 1 for each ip?

Comment: yes, the cross query output is everytime a warning with " #1054 - Unknown column 'a.ip' in 'where clause' " so i need a.ip in the cross join subquery :/

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from a cross join (select * from b where ip <= a.ip order by ip desc limit 1) aaa
```

I just addded aaa to be the name of the derived table which is required even if it is not referenced.